# backbone.js model validation isValid() returns true for invalid attribute

Tags: validation, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-events

I was trying to check the validity of individual attributes using `isValid` method. It is returning *true* for an invalid attribute. My code is as follows:

```
person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        name:"default name",
        age:0
    },

    initialize:function(){  
        this.on("invalid",function(model,errors){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(errors));
        });
    },

    validate:function(attrs){
        errors=[];
        if(attrs.age<0){
            errors.push({attribName:"age",errorMsg:"age should be grater than 0"});
        }
        return errors.length>0?errors:false;
    }
});

var person1 = new person();
person1.set({
    age:-5
});

console.log("checking validity of model:"+person1.isValid());   
console.log("checking for validity of age attribute:"+person1.isValid('age'));
```

`isValid()` works fine if used to check the validity of the model as a whole and returns false. But when I try to check the *age* attribute i.e `isValid('age')` it returns *true* when it should return *false*.

`isValid()` is an underscore.js function, right? Doesn't it support passing an attribute to check for its validity? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short version

[`Model.isValid`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-isValid) doesn't accept an attribute name as argument and has to be used on the whole model. If you don't, you're on undocumented territory and you will get weird behaviors.

To check individual attributes, you will have to set up your own mechanism.

### Long version, why you get a different value

`Model.isValid` does in fact accept an (undocumented) options hash as its first argument and it internally forwards this hash to `Model._validate` via

```
this._validate({}, _.extend(options || {}, { validate: true }))
```

trying to set a `validate` attribute to true. But at this point, `options` is a string and won't be modified by `_.extend`. _validate looks like

```
_validate: function(attrs, options) {
  if (!options.validate || !this.validate) return true;
  // ...
}
```

checking if it indeed has to validate the model, `options.validate` is *undefined* and your `isValid` call gets back a true value.

Comment: Actually i had seen a video tutorial in which the instructor had used isValid() and passed an attribute to check validity.

So i thought that maybe this was available in older versions of backbone.I checked that video again, infact he was also getting true on passing an attribute.Likely that he also wasn't aware of it.

I had checked _validate and isValid function definitions,but i still had doubt.Thanks for making this clear.

Answer (score 0):

isValid is a backbone API : http://backbonejs.org/#Model-isValid

The reason it is returning true is, the parameter accepted by isValid is an options paramter. It has to be an object.

One of the scenario you use options is :

```
validate: function(attrs, options) {
  if(options.someSpecialCheck) {
    // Perform some special checks here
  } else {
    // Perform some regular checks here
  }
}

myModel.isValid({someSpecialCheck: true});
```

Comment: Actually i had seen a tutorial in which model attribute was passed to isValid() method,which was wrong.As @nikoshr and u made it clear isValid() doesn't support this.Thanks for explaining with above code snippet,how to add additional functionality to validate function if required.